# How does System.Guid.NewGuid generate the GUID?

Tags: c#, guid

In c#, there is a function to generate GUID:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

How does C# generate the number? Is it time-dependent?

Comment: There is no `NewGuid` function in C#. You are referring to the `NewGuid` method of the `System.Guid` class which is part of .NET, not part of C#.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` uses the code from unmanaged ole32.dll. So it's not implemented in C# or .NET.